# ELK stack - How do i backfill all old logs into elasticsearch?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, back, fill, elastic-stack

Ive got ELK + filebeat set up with logs coming in, but want to backfill all the old logs into logstash/ES. How can I do this? People have mentioned deleting sincedb file and/or adding this to my logstash input.conf:

```
  file {
      path => "/var/log/xx/xx.log"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
     }
```

But I added it to my input conf and restarted logstash and still don't see old logs in Kibana. I also can't find the sincedb_* file that everyone refers to. My ELK node is a RHEL server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those files are old, it's a good idea to also add [`ignore_older => 0`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-ignore_older) to your config.

```
  file {
      path => "/var/log/ptsfd-mms/ptsfd-mms.log"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      ignore_older => 0
  }
```

Comment: Hi Val, thanks for your feedback. Adding that parameter to my config and restarting logstash and filebeat didn't backfill my logs into Kibana.

Comment: Can you start logstash with `--debug` and share your logs ?